# run hadoop ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
I have installed java by sudo apt-get install default-jdk

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

and in /home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.1/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh, I have added
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop$ bin/hadoop
ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java does not exist
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is not a java home. A java home must be a folder (not a program) with a bin directory which contains `java`, `jps`, maybe `javac` and so on. You must find your jre or jdk folder and set it as JAVA_HOME.

get `ll /usr/bin/java` and it may be a **symbolic link** to your Java path. or do `find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.x.x-openjdk` to find your java home. The parent directory of *Java* program is your JAVA_HOME and must be set with export in `hadoop-env.sh`.

Comment: It really helped a lot and saved a lot of time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not run it with Java 11 installed so i installed Java 8 and tried this : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you could run `readlink -f $(which java)` command which returns the actual path to the target file.

This will give you an output like this

```
readlink -f $(which java)                                                                                                                                                                                  
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the command:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed. How do you know that the OP installed [corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/?filtered-posts.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&filtered-posts.sort-order=desc)?